# Литература по C

Tags: массивы, книги, строки, сортировка

Какая самая хорошая книга, в которой очень хорошо объясняют про язык С, которую можно было бы скачать из Интернета, а то в универе не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А [google "книги по си site:hashcode.ru"](http://tinyurl.com/pvprsuw) не пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

А что вы желаете понять?

Особые тонкости, при разработке какого то ПО, вам не понятна функциональная часть, или же неясен синтаксис. Или же вообще непонятно абсолютно ничего?

Отталкивайтесь от того багажа, который у Вас есть уже за плечами.

Да и как можно что-либо советовать? Каждый человек по-разному воспримет ту или иную литературу.

Ищите, пробуйте, читайте, и всё самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Самое лучшее - практика. Чем быстрее приступите - тем лучше. А книга так, справочник, которую к тому же сейчас может заменить интернет.